# UIUserNotificationSettings Alert Causes App to Resign Activity

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, avaudioplayer, appdelegate

I currently have an application that requires Local Notifications, so naturally I must ask the user if he or she would like to 'Allow Notifications'. Here is how I am doing this:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
// Local Notifications
    if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    }
```

At the initial loading of the app, I have a `AVAudioPlayer` that begins playing. I have it set up so that when the user leaves the app (the application enters the background) the music fades out and pauses.

**The problem** is that during the first time the app is launched, when the notification pops up asking for the user to allow notifications, it appears that the app is *fooled* into thinking it is about to **resign activity**. I can't seem to figure out how to either avoid **JUST** the notification alert from triggering this, or at worst "bring the app back", and becoming active once the alert is dismissed with one of the 2 notification options.

Here is what I am calling in my `ViewController` to notify the app when it changes state:

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ...

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pauseAudio)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
    ...
}
```

If someone could tell me how to ignore the notification alert so that it does not think it will be resigning activity, **OR** how to bring back the application after it does "resign". I currently have these other notification handles in attempt to bring it back, but they are not called after the alert "messes everything up":

(in the same `ViewController` within `viewDidLoad`)

```
...
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(animateLoginScreen)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(resumeAudio)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

I appreciate any help on this one. Thanks!

Comment: Why is it a problem that your app is resigning being active and then becoming active due to the notifications alert?

Comment: it isn't really a "problem" as much as an annoyance - I would prefer the background FX to continue playing during the alert presentation. The issue here is that pausing the FX through the `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` allows the FX to fade out while the user finishes leaving, rather than what seems to be after the user leaves, if using `...DidEnterBackgroud...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever a "system dialog", such as the notification permission dialog, is shown your application *does* resign active because it is iOS, not your app, that is responsible for processing the permissions request.

Your app isn't 'fooled', it really is resigning active for the period of time that the dialog is displayed.  I suspect that you should pause your audio on your application entering the background, not merely on it resigning active. `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` should be posted if you are getting a willResignActive though.  Do you get a call to the corresponding AppDelegate methods?

Comment: im not quite sure however why I am receiving a notification for resigning active but not a did become active notif once the permission dialog has been closed. any idea?

Comment: is there something stopping the applicationDidBecomeActive method from being called? Im confused on how you could ever have one called without the other

Comment: I just ran a test and before the notification permissions dialog was displayed my app delegate  `applicationWillResignActive` was called and as soon as I tapped "OK" there was a call to `applicationDidBecomeActive`

Comment: now im very confused - testing this on my own personal device (iPhone 5c iOS 8.4) and the simulator (iPhone 6S iOS 9.1) I too am receiving `applicationDidBecomeActive`, however when testing on the simulator iPhone 6 iOS 9.1 there is never a call to `applicationDidBecomeActive`. I have no idea how or why, perhaps some strange glitch when I updated my Xcode? Either way I'm sure it's of no concern. Good to know i wasted 5 hours staring at something that was correct all along. thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah.  You can't trust the simulator for these sorts of things.  You should always test on a real device.